# Cupy works well with TITAN V, but not with TITAN RTX

Tags: python, pytorch, nvidia, cupy

I am using cupy to run a cuda code with pytorch.

My env is
ubuntu 20, anaconda-python 3.7.6, nvidia-driver 440, cuda 10.2, cupy-cuda102, torch 1.4.0

First, I wrote a simple main code

```
import data_load_test
from tqdm import tqdm
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

def main():

    dataset = data_load_test.DataLoadTest()
    training_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=1)
    with torch.cuda.device(0):
        pbar = tqdm(training_loader)
        for epoch in range(3):
            for i, img in enumerate(pbar):
                print("see the message")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and data loader like this.

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import cv2
import cupy as cp

def read_cuda_file(cuda_path):
    f = open(cuda_path, 'r')
    source_line = ""
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line: break
        source_line = source_line + line
    f.close()
    return source_line

class DataLoadTest(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        source = read_cuda_file("cuda/cuda_code.cu")
        cuda_source = '''{}'''.format(source)
        module = cp.RawModule(code=cuda_source)
        self.myfunc = module.get_function('myfunc')

        self.input = cp.asarray(cv2.imread("hi.png",-1), cp.uint8)
        h, w, c = self.input.shape
        self.h = h
        self.w = w
        self.output = cp.zeros((w, h, 3), dtype=cp.uint8)

        self.block_size = (32, 32)
        self.grid_size = (h // self.block_size[1], w // self.block_size[0])

    def __len__(self):
        return 1

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        self.myfunc(self.grid_size, self.block_size, (self.input, self.output, self.h, self.w))
        return cp.asnumpy(self.output)
```

And my cuda code is,

```
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846f
extern "C"{
__global__ void myfunc(const unsigned char* refImg, unsigned char* warpImg, const long long cols, const long long rows)
{

    long long x = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    long long y = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;

    long long indexImg = y * cols + x;

    warpImg[indexImg * 3] = 0;
    warpImg[indexImg * 3 + 1] = 1;
    warpImg[indexImg * 3 + 2] = 2;
}
}
```

I have two GPUs TITAN V (device 0) and TITAN RTX (device 1)

When I run this code with TITAN V,(main function 3rd line)

```
with torch.cuda.device(0):
```

it works fine, but

with TITAN RTX,

```
with torch.cuda.device(1):
```

It gives an error message like this.

```
  File "cupy/core/raw.pyx", line 66, in cupy.core.raw.RawKernel.__call__
  File "cupy/cuda/function.pyx", line 162, in cupy.cuda.function.Function.__call__
  File "cupy/cuda/function.pyx", line 144, in cupy.cuda.function._launch
  File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 293, in cupy.cuda.driver.launchKernel
  File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 118, in cupy.cuda.driver.check_status
cupy.cuda.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_CONTEXT_IS_DESTROYED: context is destroyed
```

Please help.

Comment: You probably have to force cupy to compile the code in separate modules to separate functions for each GPU,

Comment: you should provide a [mcve], see item 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), note use of the word "must".  Also note that you have `cp.cuda.Device(0).use()` **twice**.

Comment: Oh sorry, now I see that. I'll edit my question soon.

Comment: It seems like a device cupy uses can be decided by a code from pytorch -torch.cuda.device(0).
How do I force which gpu to use properly considering pytorch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main() when dataLoadTest() class is instantiated, it is happening on the default device 0, so cuPy is compiling myFunc() there.

The next line “with torch.cuda.device(0):“ is where you switch to device 1 in the version that fails?

What happens if you call

```
cuPy.cuda.Device(1).use()
```

as the first line in main(), to make sure myFunc() gets instantiated on device 1?

Comment: Oh, thank you. It works!. Now I see what's going on with devices.

Comment: I tested a few more cases, and it seems like "cp.cuda.Device(1).use()" and "with torch.cuda.device(1):" are equivalent. Are they equivalent?
For example, if I call "cp.cuda.Device(1).use()" at the first line in main(), then I don't even have to call "with torch.cuda.device(1):" later.